# Display Union Data Side By Side Without Duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I am trying to display the total sale and number of customers on a particular month based on the age group. I am able to display the result as follows:

[image: Result]

But my desired output is like this:

```
Age Group      Number of Customers       Total Sales
----------------------------------------------------
Teenager             57                   48313.26
Adult                277                 198512.89
Senior Citizen       50                      44770
```

I already tried several method like inline select and union all/union but fail to produce the desired output. My coding for the result is below:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
      WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
      ELSE 'Teenager'
    END AS "AGE GROUP",
    COUNT(*) AS "NUMBER OF CUSTOMER"
FROM customer
GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
        WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
        ELSE 'Teenager'
    END
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE
      WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
      WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
      ELSE 'Teenager'
   END AS "AGE GROUP",
   SUM(final_total) AS "TOTAL SALES"
FROM customer c, orders o
WHERE c.cust_id = o.cust_id
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_datetime) = &check_year            
GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
        WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
        ELSE 'Teenager'
    END;
```

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Mureinik and Thorsten Kettner helps, I finally get the desired output and know that I didn't look enough documentation haha.
My try of coding:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
      WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
      ELSE 'Teenager'
    END AS "AGE GROUP",
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.cust_id) AS "NUMBER OF CUSTOMER",
    SUM(final_total) AS "TOTAL SALES"
FROM customer c, orders o
WHERE c.cust_id = o.cust_id
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_datetime) = &check_year            
GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
        WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
        ELSE 'Teenager'
    END;
```

I feel so dumb that I never think of putting **DISTINCT** inside the COUNT(). But still, Mureinik code is also working for me!

Comment: On a side note: You should no longer use comma-separated joins (`FROM customer c, orders o`). They were made redundant 28 years ago with the invention of explicit joins (`FROM customer c INNERJOIN orders o ON ...`) in the SQL standard.

Comment: I expect a lot of 51 year olds will be surprised to learn that they are senior citizens.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Initially I put 55 years old as senior citizen but I found out the age of random generated data is all below 55. So I mark 50 years old as senior citizen to get some data haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest to use the WITH clause to prevent duplicate complexity?

Edited the original code to show results of two years.

```
WITH age_groups as (
  SELECT   CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - c.dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior 
  Citizen'
              WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - c.dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
              ELSE 'Teenager'
              END AS AGE_GROUP
              , c.cust_id, o.final_total
              , extract(YEAR from o.order_datetime) as year
  FROM      customer c
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
),
year1 as (
select    age_group ,
          COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS_Y1,
          SUM(final_total) AS TOTAL_SALES_Y1
FROM      age_groups
WHERE     year = &check_year1
group by age_group),
year2 as (select    age_group ,
          COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS_Y2,
          SUM(final_total) AS TOTAL_SALES_Y2
FROM      age_groups
WHERE     year = &check_year2
group by age_group)
select age_group, number_of_customers_y1, total_sales_y1
                , number_of_customers_y2, total_sales_y2
from year1 join year2 using(age_group);
```

Comment: Yep, that's a good idea. While the original `GROUP BY` clause is only copy and paste from the `SELECT` clause, it is still a tad better to have the expression in only one place in the query. You are missing the restriction on orders, though, that was missing from Mureinik's answer, too, until it was added. And in a query dealing with multiple tables, all columns should be qualified with their table (`c.dob` instead of `dob`, `o.final_total` instead of `final_total`).

Comment: This is new to me. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you Thorsten, for your comment. I've edited my answer accoringly. One other change I've made is to move the extra restriction from the on part of the FROM clause to the WHERE clause: ON is only meant for the join condition between the tables, other restrictions should be in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Marko Hi, sorry to bother, wanna ask whether is it possible to compare two years with the method you provide? Like the code you provide will be one of the years, and I add up another nested left join to show the second years of user input.

Comment: @Key I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I've edited my code to include the year in the inline view.

Comment: @Marko Erm..almost what I need but I would like to separate the column to year 1 and year 2 for total sales and customer number. I tried to use your suggested method by using 2 WITH clause, but I fail as the number of customers will only show one year correct, the other is the total existing number of customer and the total sales is not correct also. As I am using group by, so is it possible to get the desired output by using 2 WITH clause with the almost exactly same of coding? Thank you for answering me btw =D

Comment: Hi @Key, maybe this is what you want? You can build upon a previous with clause with a following with clause. In this example I have the results of two years in two extra columns. What you could also do is just do  a group by of both age_group and year.

Comment: @Marko Omg yes! This is what I am looking for. Thank you really much! I am doing fine by using the cursor to get the result and I found it very difficult to do it in one single query. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome @Key :-)  In general, I think every one should make better use of the with clause than is commonly done. It's a great way to set up your query in a modular way.

Answer (score 3):

You can query both aggregate terms from a join on the two tables. Note that a `left join` is preferable here in case you have customers without orders (not sure if this is possible in your data, but just in case):

```sql
SELECT   CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - c.dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
              WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - c.dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
              ELSE 'Teenager'
              END AS "AGE GROUP",
          COUNT(DISTINCT c.cust_id) AS "NUMBER OF CUSTOMER",
          SUM(o.final_total) AS "TOTAL SALES"
FROM      customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id
                   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.order_datetime) = &check_year
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - c.dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 50 ) THEN 'Senior Citizen'
               WHEN (EXTRACT(Year From (SYSDATE - c.dob) YEAR TO MONTH) > 25 ) THEN 'Adult'
               ELSE 'Teenager'
          END;
```

Comment: The result is definitely what I want, but the result of the total sales is inaccurate. I think is because I had 30000++ orders records and only 300++ customers and after randomize the data, each customer have at least 10 records. I also got looks at left join, self inner, right join documentation but I think it does not suit my case. But still very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @Key: The query looks correct. You can easily control the numbers via `select sum(final_total) from orders`. This should equal the sum over Mureinik's totals, proving that their query is correct.

Comment: Oh wait! Omg I saw the **DISTINCT c.cust_id** and it give me an idea! I manage to get the desired output. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I think the result is incorrect because he miss out the condition for the total sales of order, which is based on the year of the order date. But still thanks for helping, I will look at some documentation to know more about join as I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @Key: Ah, you are right. So just add `AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.order_datetime) = &check_year` to the `ON` clause. I've updated Mureinik's answer accordingly.